# how to disable crawlers for a subdomain pointing to the same root of the main domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I have activated cloudfare cdn service on one of my sites,
and I have created a direct.mydomain.com
subdomain to bypass cloudfare cache when working on the site.

I want to avoid crawling and indexing of this subdomain, as it would results in duplicate contents.
Usually I use robots.txt file to do this, but the problem here is that due to the fact that my subdomain points to the same directory of the main domain the robots.txt file is the same for the two of them.

Any idea on how could I do this

here is the cloudfare support topic I opened about this issue
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/requests/85756

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to forward all requests for `robots.txt` to a different custom file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^direct\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-banned.txt [NC,L]
```

Then in your `/robots-banned.txt` file have this code:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but this create some sort of conflict because when I create the subdomain direct.mydomain.com in cpanel, a redirect to robots-direct.txt (this is the name of my robots file for this subdomain, instead that robots-banned.txt as you suggested) is automatically being created, 

so when I try to visit the site using direct.mydomain.com I get a 404 error, because the browser try to redirect me to that file which is in /public_html

this direct subdomain should allow me to surf the site normally, I just want the search engines to not crawl and index it

Comment: That is very strange since above rule will act ONLY when request for `robots.txt` arrives and that only comes from crawlers, not from regular browsers. `robots-banned.txt` was just an example you can use `robots-direct.txt` as well.

Comment: well, maybe the problem was due to something else, because I just tried to re-apply your suggestion, and now it works! thank you so much for the help :-)